# How to set MQRFH2 NameValueCCSID in IBM MQ Mule 4

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

I am unable to set the NameValueCCSID in the IBM MQ connector in the Mule 4, by default it is always going as 1208 to the target server(iseries) which is unexpected. Any advice on this please?

Comment: I am thinking by default the encoding is UTF-8. If you change the encoding to whatever you need, then it will set the respective CCSID.

Comment: Are you using MQGMO_CONVERT in the getting application running on iSeries? I don't believe your can set NameValueCCSID to anything, only a select few possibilities and none are EBCDIC.